# Im having trouble finding the Big O notation for these code segments

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, big-o

```
1. 

    for(i=0; i<N, i+=2)
    for(j=0; j<i; j+=2)
     a[i] += i*j;
    printf("Elements: ");
    for(i=N; i>0; i--)
     printf("%d ", a[i]);

2. while(N) {
 printf("%d ", N);
 N /= 2;
}
```

In the first question i know because its a nested for loop so i will get O(n^2), but as there is another for loop im not really sure.
for the second loop i cant understand what will happen when N/2.

Comment: You really ought to fix up your indentation, for readability..

Comment: A repetitive multiplication is an exponential, a repetitive division is a logarithm (inverse function of exponential).

Comment: Re-format the code using curly brackets and indentations. It's hard to determine which statements are in which loops without them.

Comment: Don't just memorize things like "a nested loop is O(n^2)," because that's not always true. If the condition in the inner loop were, say, `j < 100`, then the complexity of that nested pair of loops would just be O(n).

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, the second loop is `O(N)`. Hence the nested loop's complexity, `O(N^2)`, prevails.

For the second question, you are dividing `N` by 2 in every iteration. Its complexity is going to be `O(log(N))`.